# Connecting to Information Security SE somehow disconnected me from other sites

Tags: support, login

Information Security asked me to "join" and when I did, it (as I expected from previous sites) **seemed** to accept my existing info from other sites.  But afterward, Travel asked me to join instead of allowing a log in.

Why?  What should I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure *what* went sideways there, but I merged your new account with your old one. You should be able to access it again without problems. Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, yes, it looks like me now, but the profile page incorrectly suggests that I have had no activity since 18 July.  Oops, never mind.  I was looking at the Meta profile.  The Travel looks correct.  Thanks.